# elixir 0.14.1 error on mix (No file named /usr/local/bin/mix)

Tags: homebrew, elixir

I have installed Elixir 0.14.1 and Erlang 17.1 on my mac by homebrew

When I tried to run the **mix** command I get the following error:

> $ mix new example
>
> No file named /usr/local/bin/mix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a regression on Erlang 17.1. We are releasing Elixir 0.14.2 today that will address this particular bug.

Comment: @Jose facing the problem in mac os with intellij idea and elixir 1.4.1

Answer (score 1):

Just want to add: if you are using Homebrew, make sure to run `brew update` before running `brew upgrade elixir` so you can get the latest formula.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very sure if this is the way to fix the error, I'm very new to the language and what I did and now **mix** is working is:

> $ brew unlink elixir
>   $ brew install elixir --HEAD

Any ideas? Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

New update, no need to do a brew install elixir --HEAD

just to update to the latest elixir 0.14.2 will work.